# Radon-Nikodym Derivative and Average of Densities

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be probability measures on a measure space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{M})$. We observe that both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to the measure $\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}$, and hence $\mu$ admits a density (Radon-Nikodym derivative) $p = \frac{d\mu}{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)}$ and $\nu$ admits a density (Radon-Nikodym derivative) $q = \frac{d\nu}{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)}$ with respect to $\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}$.

Before I continue, I use three properties of the Radon-Nikodym derivative that **I believe are true** (but I'm not sure): $\frac{d(\mu+\nu)}{d\kappa} = \frac{d\mu}{d\kappa} + \frac{d\nu}{d\kappa}$, if $C \geq 0$, then $\frac{d(C\mu)}{d\kappa} = C\frac{d\mu}{d\kappa}$, and $\frac{d\mu}{d\mu} = 1$. Now I do the following calculation:

$$1 = \frac{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)}{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d\mu}{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d\nu}{d\left(\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}\right)} = \frac{p+q}{2}$$

Is this above calculation correct? It seems bizarre to me that $\frac{p(x)+q(x)}{2} = 1$ for both $\mu$- and $\nu$-almost every $x \in \mathcal{X}$. If it is correct, does anyone have an explanation for what is going on?

Comment: It's correct - of the three properties you use, the first two follow from linearity of integration, and the third is a triviality. Why do you find this bizzare? The same phenomenon occurs for fractions - $ \frac{a}{(a+b)} + \frac{b}{(a+b)} = 1.$ Is this also bizzare? (I'm asking this sincerely - to me this seems, well, obvious, so I'd like to understand what throws you about this, both to get a sense of a different perspecive and to figure out what sort of an explanation would help).

Comment: Modulo technical details, denoting $\lambda=\frac{\mu+\nu}{2}$, we have $\int_Ad\lambda=\lambda(A)=\frac{\mu(A)+\nu(A)}{2}=\int_A\frac{p+q}{2}d\lambda$ for every measurable $A$, hence $1=\frac{p+q}{2}$ a.e..

Comment: Maybe I'm over thinking this. Thanks.

Comment: It confused me because I was thinking in terms of averages and densities. Why does the average of the densities, for almost all $x \in \mathcal{X}$, equal $1$?